# How to convert a character into an integer in Java?

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

I am a beginner at Java, trying to figure out how to convert characters from a text file into integers. In the process, I wrote a program which generates a text file showing what characters are generated by what integers.

```
package numberchars;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.Character;

public class Numberchars {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

FileWriter outputStream = new FileWriter("NumberChars.txt");

//Write to the output file the char corresponding to the decimal
// from 1 to 255
int counter = 1;

while (counter <256)
{
outputStream.write(counter);

outputStream.flush();
counter++;
}
outputStream.close();
```

This generated NumberChars.txt, which had all the numbers, all the letters both upper and lower case, surrounded at each end by other symbols and glyphs.

Then I tried to read this file and convert its characters back into integers:

```
FileReader inputStream = new FileReader("NumberChars.txt");
FileWriter outputStream2 = new FileWriter ("CharNumbers.txt");
int c;

while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1)
            {
                outputStream2.write(Character.getNumericValue(c));
                outputStream2.flush();
            }  

}


}
```

The resulting file, `CharNumbers.txt`, began with the same glyphs as NumberChars.txt but then was blank. Opening the files in MS Word, I found NumberChars had 248 characters (including 5 spaces) and CharNumbers had 173 (including 8 spaces).

So why didn't the `Character.getNumericValue(c)` result in an integer written to CharNumbers.txt? And given that it didn't, why at least didn't it write an exact copy of NumberChars.txt? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Character.getNumericValue` doesn't do what you think it does. If you read the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-int-):

> Returns the `int` value that the specified character (Unicode code point) represents. For example, the character `'\u216C'` (the Roman numeral fifty) will return an int with a value of `50`.

On error it returns `-1` (which looks like `0xFF_FF_FF_FF` in 2s complement).

Most characters don't have such a "numeric value," so you write the ints out, each padded to 2 bytes (more on that later), read them back in the same way, and then start writing a whole lot of `0xFFFF` (`-1` truncated to 2 bytes) courtesy of a misplaced `Character.getNumericValue`. I'm not sure *what* MS Word is doing, but it's probably getting confused what the encoding of your file is and glomming all those bytes into `0xFF_FF_FF_FF` (because the high bits of each byte are set) and treating that as one character. (Use a text editor more suited to this kind of stuff like Notepad++, btw.) If you were to measure your file's size on disk in bytes it will probably still be `256 chars * 2 bytes/chars = 512 bytes`.

I'm not sure what you meant to do here, so I'll note that `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` work on a (Unicode) character basis, with an encoder that defaults to the system one. That's why your ints are padded/truncated to 2 bytes. If you wanted pure byte IO, use `FileInputStream`/`FileOutputStream`. If you wanted to read and write the `int`s as `String`s, you need to use `FileWriter`/`FileReader`, but not like you did.

```
// Just bytes
// This is a try-with-resources. It executes the code with the decls in it
// but is also like an implicit finally block that calls `close()` on each resource.
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("bytes.bin")) {
    for(int b = 0; b < 256; b++) { // Bytes are signed so we use int.
          // This takes an int and truncates it for the lowest byte
          fos.write(b);
          // Can also fill a byte[] and dump it all at once with overloaded write.
    }
}
byte[] bytes = new bytes[256];
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("bytes.bin")) {
    // Reads up to bytes.length bytes into bytes
    fis.read(bytes);
}

// Foreach loop. If you don't know what this does, I think you can figure out from the name.
for(byte b : bytes) {
    System.out.println(b);
}

// As Strings
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("strings.txt")) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        // You need a delimiter lest you not be able to tell 12 from 1,2 when you read
        // Uses system default encoding
        fw.write(Integer.toString(i) + "\n");
    }
}
byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
try(
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("strings.txt");
    // FileReaders can't do stuff like "read one line to String" so we wrap it
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        bytes[i] = Byte.valueOf(br.readLine());
    }
}

for(byte b : bytes) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyCLAss {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        char x='b';
        System.out.println(+x);//just by witting a plus symbol before the variable you can find it's ascii value....it will give 98.
    }

}
```